# yum is not working after entering in command in RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

I entered in a command:

```
$ rpm -e --nodeps python
```

and after that I get this when I try to enter in something with `yum`:

```
-bash: /bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So what is the best way to get `yum` back since it broke after entering in the  `rpm -e --nodeps python`?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you have the `.rpm` kicking around; you used `rpm` to remove it; just use `rpm` to reinstall it.  And be more careful with `--nodeps` in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall python. Redhat or even yum requires python 2

If you dont have the rpm, it is available from the distro, so you could mount the iso (if you have it to hand)and get it from there, or download the python 2.7 rpm to your server. Cd to the directory the downloaded rpm is in.

Install it with something like:

```
rpm -ivh python*
```

Then you need might need to point /usr/bin/python to python2.6

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I'm getting
error: File not found by glob: python* after entering in
rpm -ivh python*

Comment: If you have another RHEL system with the same release, you can use `yumdownloader` on it to download the RPM, then copy it to your system and run `rpm` as in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the rpm package of **Python** you need to reinstall it again.

[Go to Below URL and wget latest new python package](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/)

> wget "python-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64.rpm"

something like this and install it with {rpm} cmd

why we need this package, because yum utility uses python package.

Regards,

Wajid Shaikh